# UIBarButtonIteem common to all controllers

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have the current structure:

- Nagivation Controller:

  - Tab bar controller:

    - Custom view controller / Table
    - Custom view controller / Table
    - Custom view controller / Collection

A navigation controller that contains a tab bar controller and which contains several custom view controllers.

I need to add the same button to the navigation bar of all controllers, and run the very same code. All I can think of is copying the same code in all controllers but I feel it's a little hacky, there must be a proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Create a sub class of a UINavigation Controller and make all your navigation controllers a subclass of it. Then simply add your bar button there.

Comment: As my question says, I only have ONE nav controller, the rest are custom view controllers, they already subclass some other classes

Comment: You could have a HelperClass with a method that returns the custom uibarbuttonitem something like `[HelperClass barButtonItem];`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a utility class and write the code for implementing the button in a method. Then import this class to all the view controllers and simply call the method. This should solve the problem of copying redundant code in all the view controllers.